# Windows 7 (user error)

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting

I have Dell Ispirion Mini 1012 with Windows Starter.

User DELETED the "C:\USERS" folder.

After RESTART, windows boots normally, but it gets stuck on the desktop, I can only access Google Chrome.

I tried to host a join.me session and control computer that way, but it's the same.

Do you have any idea, how can I fix this the quickest way possible ( without re-installing Windows )
?

Comment: A bit surprising that a user can delete the C:\Users folder as it should say that it is currently used. Can you Ctrl Alt Del and open Task Manager? And from Task Manager, you can open a Command Prompt (File - New Task - Run - CMD) and create a new user from CMD?

Comment: @Rujke - Its getting stuck on the desktop because the entire user profile directory is gone.  He will have to create a new user to resolve his booting problems.  There is the default Administrator account built-in `Windows 7` that works for that.

Comment: I have access only to Google Chrome, everything else is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Get your hands on a Windows 7 Install CD (if you don't have a physical cd, grab an ISO from MSDN) and boot into that. Your best bet would be first to try a system restore. Choose 'System Restore' from the System Recovery Options Dialog, and try and find a restore point that is before the deletion occurred.

If that doesn't work, you should try copying over:

`C:\Users\default`

from another machine. This should at least allow you to re-create working user accounts. You'll probably need to activate the Administrator account through a cmd prompt off the recovery disk. The command to do that is:

`net user administrator /active:yes`

If you don't have a System Restore Point available, or that does not work, [kb947215](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215) may be helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. While in "Resume Windows Screen" I used "SPACE" to stop that process, that gave me another screen prompting for option 1 (Enter Windows Normally) and option 2 (Delete Configuration Files and Enter Windows). I used option 2, and all issues are solved.